# BTEQ "Create set table" equivalent in Snowflake sql

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to know the equivalent query of Teradata BTEQ "create set table" in Snowflake SQL. I'm working on query conversion between BTEQ to Snowflake. Is there any direct syntax? If not, how can I create a set(Allows only unique values/records) table?

Comment: I don't know any other DBMS to support SET tables. SET is equivalent to a Primary Key across all columns of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake doesn't have this functionality, and I don't know any database other than Teradata that does.

You can try to emulate that e.g. by always inserting data using a temporary staging table and then `MERGE` or `INSERT..SELECT..`, explicitly avoiding duplicates (on the loading side), or access the data through a view that does `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table`.